Leaflet perimeter of polygons
I'm trying to add a total length to the last drawn point of polygons, leaflet-draw already works for polylines and has the the parameter showLength: true, that shows the total length at the last point. But I can't seem to find a way to add the total length to polygons without having to addhooks and so on.
How can I add showlength: true or some itteration of it to the polygons?
For reference this is how my polygon is defined in leaflet draw
L.Draw.Polygon = L.Draw.Polygon.include({
    statics: {
        TYPE: 'polygon'
    },
    Poly: L.Polygon,
    options: {
        showArea: false,
        showLength: true,
        shapeOptions: {
            stroke: true,
            color: '#3388ff',
            weight: 4,
            opacity: 0.5,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: null,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            clickable: true,
            showMeasurements: true
        },
        drawError: {
            color: '#b00b00',
            timeout: 2500
        },
        metric: true,
        feet: true,
        nautic: false,
        precision: {}
    },
});

